# Can this hierarchy be evaluated at higher levels?

Tags: ordinals

I defined a hierarchy as follows:

$F_{\alpha+1}(n) = \sum{^n_{m=1}} F_\alpha(m)$, or the sum of F_a(1) + F_a(2) + ... + F_a(n)

If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $F_\alpha(n) = F_{\alpha[n]}(n)$.

The first few values of $F_\omega$ are 1, 2, 6, 20, 70, 252, ... (the central binomial coefficients) and the first few values of $F_{\omega^2}$ are 1, 4, 36, 440, 6650... but at higher levels, the hierarchy becomes very difficult to evaluate, and even $F_{\omega^\omega}$ gets hard to evaluate after the third value (216). It took me a whole evening last week just to evaluate $F_{\varepsilon_0}(3) = 306030478267498284$.

Is there an efficient way to evaluate higher-level expressions in this hierarchy?

Comment: You are supposed to give a more specific task (e.g. calculate $F_{\varepsilon_0}(3)$), rather than asking for evaluating *this hierarchy*. Also, if it is not known whether there is an efficient answer, then this question would be suitable for the mathoverflow site, which is for discussion of research problems.

Comment: Some specific values I want to find: F_w^w(4), F_w^w(5), F_w^w^2(4). Very large values like F_w^w^w^2(3) (> 3^19683) and F_e_0(4) would be very hard if not impossible to exactly evaluate.